# Twitter API - unable to get coordinates from standard search query

Tags: twitter

I'm currently encountering an issue. I am trying to get recent tweets using Twitter's [standard search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets). I am using the following query:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=&geocode=40.7369547,-73.9912154,5mi&result_type=recent
```

This successfully fetches recent tweets within a 5 mile radius from the given coordinates. However, part of my task is to place these tweets on a map. What I'm finding is that NONE of the results returned from the standard search API return the coordinates of the tweet. I've increased my search radius to try to find something with coordinates that I can place on a map, but I can't find a single valid tweet from this API.

In the response object for every tweet, the geo and coordinate values are always null. I very rarely find a tweet where the "places" object is not null, but this object forms a bounding area where the tweet came from, rather than exact coordinates.

I'm pretty lost here. Is this the correct Twitter API to be using for this task? How come the geo and coordinate values are always null, even if I find the geo_enabled flag is true in the response object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, very few users choose to add location information to Tweets (the value is a single digit percentage). `coordinates` is populated when an app adds a precise lat/lon location to a Tweet. This feature was [removed in Twitter’s own apps a few months ago](https://twittercommunity.com/t/recent-tweet-compose-update-might-affect-some-geo-use-cases/126982), although users can still use a `place` in the Tweet Composer. Third party apps that use the API might still use the exact location and thus the `coordinates` value may be populated. In general, a smaller proportion of Tweets will now have `coordinates` included that was true in the past.

Comment: Yikes. So perhaps it's worth sending these requirements back as no longer feasible.